# Weird terminal behavior after installing RVM

Tags: rvm

I installed RVM and added this line to the end of my `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Now, whenever I enter a command into my terminal I get a `[Process Completed]` error and my session ends. This error goes away when I remove this line from my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias :='cd ..'
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because ':' is a builtin for 'true' that you are overriding. You should *never* override [shell builtins][1] with alias's.

RVM uses ':' in several places (as it should, it is a shell builtin!) and so when you overrode it will cause... odd behavior.

[1]: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Builtins -- See the '' builtin.